# Javascript Parsing JSON from PHP echo throw error, AJAX Parsing works correctly

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am having an issue parsing a JSON string returned from php on page load.
The weird is that if I make a ajax request to the same function, it parses without any error.

The problem occures when I try this

```
JSON.parse('{"products":[{"id":"1","name":"Batata Frita ","description":"<p>Batata ta<strong> frita&nbsp;<\/strong><strong>pizza<\/strong><\/p>","short_description":"Batata ta frita","type":"food","category_id":"1","price":"15.00","inventory":"100","image":"\\tmp\\catalog\\productmenu\\batata_frita_sequinhaaa_1.jpg","options":"[{\"is_delete\":\"\",\"previous_type\":\"\",\"previous_group\":\"\",\"id\":\"1\",\"option_id\":1,\"title\":\"Molhos\",\"type\":\"drop_down\",\"is_require\":\"1\",\"values\":[{\"option_type_id\":0,\"is_delete\":\"\",\"title\":\"Ketchup\",\"price\":\"5\",\"sku\":\"\",\"sort_order\":\"\"}]},{\"is_delete\":\"\",\"previous_type\":\"\",\"previous_group\":\"\",\"id\":\"2\",\"option_id\":2,\"title\":\"Adicionais\",\"type\":\"checkbox\",\"is_require\":\"1\",\"values\":{\"1\":{\"option_type_id\":1,\"is_delete\":\"\",\"title\":\"Cebola\",\"price\":\"2\",\"sku\":\"\",\"sort_order\":\"\"},\"2\":{\"option_type_id\":2,\"is_delete\":\"\",\"title\":\"Queijo\",\"price\":\"5\",\"sku\":\"\",\"sort_order\":\"\"}}},{\"is_delete\":\"\",\"previous_type\":\"\",\"previous_group\":\"\",\"id\":\"3\",\"option_id\":3,\"title\":\"Teste\",\"type\":\"field\",\"is_require\":\"1\",\"price\":\"5\",\"price_type\":\"fixed\",\"sku\":\"\",\"max_characters\":\"\"},{\"is_delete\":\"\",\"previous_type\":\"\",\"previous_group\":\"\",\"id\":\"4\",\"option_id\":4,\"title\":\"Hor\\u00e1rio de entrega\",\"type\":\"date_time\",\"is_require\":\"1\",\"price\":\"10\",\"sku\":\"\"}]","barcode":"77373737737","store_ids":"2","seller_id":"67","status":"1","image_path":"http:\/\/192.100.2.109\/test\/media\/\\tmp\\catalog\\productmenu\\batata_frita_sequinhaaa_1.jpg"},{"id":"2","name":"Pizza","description":"<p>Pizza 30cm<\/p>","short_description":"Pizza 30cm","type":"food","category_id":"2","price":"44.00","inventory":"200","image":"\\tmp\\catalog\\productmenu\\pizzadem.jpg","options":"[{\"is_delete\":\"\",\"previous_type\":\"\",\"previous_group\":\"\",\"id\":\"1\",\"option_id\":1,\"title\":\"Sabor 1\",\"type\":\"drop_down\",\"is_require\":\"1\",\"values\":[{\"option_type_id\":0,\"is_delete\":\"\",\"title\":\"Calabresa\",\"price\":\"10\",\"sku\":\"\",\"sort_order\":\"\"},{\"option_type_id\":1,\"is_delete\":\"\",\"title\":\"Muzzarela\",\"price\":\"5\",\"sku\":\"\",\"sort_order\":\"\"}]},{\"is_delete\":\"\",\"previous_type\":\"\",\"previous_group\":\"\",\"id\":\"2\",\"option_id\":2,\"title\":\"Sabor 2\",\"type\":\"drop_down\",\"is_require\":\"1\",\"values\":{\"2\":{\"option_type_id\":2,\"is_delete\":\"\",\"title\":\"Bacon\",\"price\":\"15\",\"sku\":\"\",\"sort_order\":\"\"},\"3\":{\"option_type_id\":3,\"is_delete\":\"\",\"title\":\"Muzzarela\",\"price\":\"10\",\"sku\":\"\",\"sort_order\":\"\"}}}]","barcode":"324324","store_ids":"2","seller_id":"67","status":"1","image_path":"http:\/\/192.100.2.109\/test\/media\/\\tmp\\catalog\\productmenu\\pizzadem.jpg"},{"id":"3","name":"Agua","description":"<p>Agua 500ml<\/p>","short_description":"Agua 500ml","type":"drink","category_id":"3","price":"5.00","inventory":"200","image":"\\tmp\\catalog\\productmenu\\Download.jpg","options":null,"barcode":"324324234234","store_ids":"2","seller_id":"67","status":"1","image_path":"http:\/\/192.100.2.109\/test\/media\/\\tmp\\catalog\\productmenu\\Download.jpg"}],"categories":[{"id":"1","name":"Aperitivos","icon":"A","sort_order":"0","seller_id":"67"},{"id":"2","name":"Pizzas","icon":"P","sort_order":"1","seller_id":"67"},{"id":"3","name":"Bebidas","icon":"B","sort_order":"3","seller_id":"67"}]}')
```

The JSON String from above is echoed from PHP like following:

```
function initializeData() {
 initialData = JSON.parse('<?php echo Mage::helper('module/endpoint')->getData(); ?>')
 ...
```

Even though the JSON is valid and tested ( [JSON Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) ), it returns this error:

```
VM3617:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 248
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at <anonymous>:1:6
```

But if make a ajax request to my server and parse it (data returned is exactly the same string):

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('module/enpoint/getData') ?>',
  data: {id: sellerId, store_id: storeId},
  success: function (data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data)
    ...
```

It works without any errors.

Am I missing something here?
What could be the purpose of this behaviour?

Comment: You don't have to use `JSON.parse()` if you are dropping the JSON directly into JavaScript. JSON is valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing something here?

A common concept when dealing with strings are *escape sequences*. Those are multi-character sequences that represent a single character.

Things get tricky when you nested multiple "languages" that have this concept. In your case: JSON and JavaScript string literals.

This is valid JSON:

```
{"value": "\\c"}
```

The sequence `"\\c"` gets processed by the JSON parser and converts it to the *value* `\c`. In JSON, `\\` is the escape sequence for a single `\`.

But if you put that same value inside a JavaScript *string literal*, things start to fall apart:

```
'{"value": "\\c"}'
```

Because `\` is also the escape character in string literals, the string *value* created from this string *literal* is:

```
{"value": "\c"}
```

Just like with JSON, in JavaScript string *literals* `\\` is the escape sequence for a single `\`.

If this value is now passed to the JSON parser it sees `"\c"`, which is not a valid escape sequence so the parser throws an error.

---

> But if make a ajax request to my server and parse it ... It works without any errors.

Because there is no string *literal* in this case. The string *value* you pass to `JSON.parse` literally contains the character sequence `\\c` which is valid in JSON.

Comment: So in theory I need to first pass the JSON string to a javascript function and then parse from inside the function to avoid the string literal, not tested yet

Comment: That's not necessary. You just need to avoid using a string literal. As Pointy mentioned in their comment, since JSON is also valid JavaScript, just do `initialData = <?php echo Mage::helper('module/endpoint')->getData(); ?>;`. No parsing necessary.